# Is there a way to check when was the last time a external JS resource is updated?

Tags: javascript, file, server, ftp

I would like to know the last updated date of a resource which is external javascript.

For example:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/d3js/5.15.0/d3.min.js

Is there a way, when this resource is last updated?

Answer (score 0):

I think not directly, but you can check out the version number and then check the github project when this release was made. I would assume google will automatically host the new version.

In you case the release was made on 29 December 2019.

https://github.com/d3/d3/releases

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```js
$("button").on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: $('input[name=url]').val(),
        type: 'HEAD',
        success: function(data, textStatus, request){
            $("#output").text(request.getResponseHeader('Last-Modified'));
        },
        error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#output").text(request.getResponseHeader('Last-Modified'));
        } 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="url" placeholder="URL">
<button type="button">Check</button>
<br/><br/>
<div id="output"></div>
```